rsync command from .cpanel.yml is not updating deploy directory after git commit
I am trying to deploy to a separate folder when I commit changes. However, for one of my folders, it deploys properly, but for the other, nothing happens. No file's are updated, removed, or added.
My repository exists in repo, which is a reproduction of the folders and files that I wish to track and change with this git repository.
Commiting should see the files deployed to their correct locations within my server.
My .cpanel.yml file:
---
deployment:
  tasks:

#sends files to the backend
#this works as expected: files are changed, and switching between branches is reflected.
    - export DEPLOYPATH=/home/USER/backend
    - export REPOPATH=/home/USER/repo/backend
    - /bin/rsync -aP --exclude={'.git', '.well-known'} ${REPOPATH}/ ${DEPLOYPATH} --delete-after --exclude 'error_log*'

#sends files to the frontend
#this does not work, not changes in sitefolder on commmits or deploy HEAD
    - export DEPLOYPATH=/home/USER/public_html/sitefolder
    - export REPOPATH=/home/USER/repo/public_html/sitefolder
    - /bin/rsync -aP --exclude={'.git', '.well-known'} ${REPOPATH}/ ${DEPLOYPATH} --delete-after --exclude 'error_log*' --exclude '.well-known' --exclude 'cgi-bin'

If I run rsync -aP --exclude={'.git', '.well-known'} /home/USER/repo/public_html/sitefolder/ /home/USER/public_html/sitefolder --delete-after --exclude 'error_log*' --exclude '.well-known' --exclude 'cgi-bin' directly in the terminal, it works properly and the files are transfered.
I know that I am not providing mcuh information, but I cannot find where to see error codes for the cpanel YAML. Where can I find these?
